# What does this kind of C++ class declaration mean?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I downloaded Ogre3D source code, and found this kind of class declaration:

```
class _OgreExport TimeIndex
{ ...
```

I know "TimeIndex" is the class name, but what is the "_OgreExport" in the middle? CPP reference doesn't include this kind of class declaration form. What is this?

Comment: Not the issue, but `_OgreExport` reflects a misunderstanding on the part of the library writer. It starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter, so it's reserved to the implementation. Unfortunately, many library writers think that because they are writing a library they are part of the implementation. They're not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_OgreExport` is a preprocessor directive that expands to either

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```

when the file is included outside its module or

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

otherwise. Under Windows, you have to specify which classes/methods you want exported/imported so that they can be used across binaries.

Technically, as James pointed out in the comments, the macro name is illegal, since it begins with an underscore. These names are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: In proper C++, `_OrgeExport` must be a macro which expands to nothing.  (Actually, in proper C++, `_OrgeExport` is undefined behavior, so it could be anything.)  The macro you suggest is often used for the Windows extention you describe, with conditional expansion to nothing unless you're compiling under Windows.

Comment: @JamesKanze although, it could be part of the compiler :P

Answer (score 3):

see this code from [OgrePlatform.h:138](http://code.google.com/codesearch#uqJ9JRFhZl0/trunk/Ogre-1.7/OgreMain/include/OgrePlatform.h&q=_OgreExport&type=cs&l=138)

```
#       if defined( OGRE_NONCLIENT_BUILD )
#           define _OgreExport __declspec( dllexport )
#       else
#           if defined( __MINGW32__ )
#               define _OgreExport
#           else
#               define _OgreExport __declspec( dllimport )
#           endif
#       endif
#       define _OgrePrivate
#   endif
```

I highly recommend using [google code search](http://code.google.com/codesearch) if you have further questions of this type. Just enter, e.g., _OgreExport and see how other used it or how it is defined.

Comment: Which still doesn't tell you what it's doing.  Nor the fact that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't it helpful to rather give a hint on a useful approach than to hand the solution on a silver platter? The question was "what is the `OgreExport` in the middle", which I answered. And the asker already looked at CPP reference, which is good. Thus I expect it to be possible, once this code snippet is found, to quickly google for `__declspec` and find all the necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro that expands to something like [`__declspec(dllexport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3y1sfaz2.aspx), marking the class to be exported by the linker.